# Can't run Python code in Sublime Text 3 - Getting Error

Tags: python, sublimetext3

[Background: I installed Sublime Text 3 on Windows 64 bit and installed the Anaconda package. i'm using a Python 3.5 build system. I set up my sublime by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFciV6Ew5r4

I'm getting this error when trying to run/build the Python code.

```
[1]
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3.5', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\Seve\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3\\Code.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\Seve\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Seve\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Seve\AppData\Local\atom\bin]
```

What do I have to do to get this to work?

I am also getting this error on startup:
[Startup Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBXpK.png)

Comment: Your system is trying to find python on /usr/local/bin/python3.5 which is a Linux based path.

Answer (score 0):

Your startup error and sublime error is due to the fact that your python is not set up properly. Your sublime and anaconda are looking for python in windows generic path under C directory but you have somehow entered through CMD a wrong path